# #define error for invalid operands to binary / lvalue

Tags: c

I don't know why I am being penalized; I am copying parts of someone's code into this question... that is why I am asking for help I didn't assume I understood what they did.

I'm fixing someone else's code, this is an example:

```
#define mauldiv3c(x, y, o) o[0]=x[0]/c; o[1]=x[1]/c; o[2]=x[2]/c
```

I got the error

```
 maul.h:29:37: error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'double' and
'double *')  #define mauldiv3c(x, y, o) o[0]=x[0]/c; o[1]=x[1]/c;
o[2]=x[2]/c
```

Is this because he didn't include c as a var? Or is this an lvalue issue?

Here is the function he/she used it in:

```
/* point in triangle? */
int maulpit(double *t0, double *t1, double *t1, double *p) 
{
  double t, a[3], b[3], c[3];

  mauladd3(t1, t0, a);
  mauladd3(t2, t0, b);
  mauladd3(t2, t1, c);

  mauldiv3c(a, 2.0, a);
  mauldiv3c(b, 2.0, b);
  mauldiv3c(c, 2.0, c);

  maulsub3(t2, a, a);
  maulsub3(t1, b, b);
  maulsub3(t0, c, c);

  maulnorm3d(a);
  maulnorm3d(b);
  maulnorm3d(c);

  return( ((mauldot3(a, p))>=0.0) && 
      ((mauldot3(b, p))=>0.0) &&
      ((mauldot3(c, p))=>0.0) );
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, people should not write code like that! Can you show us line 29 so that we can see how they were using the macro?

Comment: This is just rubbish! Use a(n inline) function for this with proper types. And see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Either `x[ ]`  or `c` is of type `double *` .

Comment: And how do you use this macro?

Comment: Again, I didn't write it. So please read before you judge...

Comment: As I already guessed in my comment. `c` is an array and it will converted to `double *` in expressions `o[0]=x[0]/c; o[1]=x[1]/c; o[2]=x[2]/c`.

Comment: Neither the macros, or this thread in/out of chat, is not going to end well.

Comment: maulpit() has two parameters with the same name: cannot compile.  This is just noise code:(

Answer (score 2):

Based on how `mauldiv3c` is used, my guess is that the definition should be

```
#define mauldiv3c(x, c, o) o[0]=x[0]/c; o[1]=x[1]/c; o[2]=x[2]/c
```

`y` is never used in the macro expanaio, whereas `c` is, so it doesn't make sense that the macro's second parameter is `y`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `c` is an array, which decays to a pointer when you use it in expressions like that. You can't divide a value by an array.